# MySQL select by month returns NULL for all months

Tags: mysql, sql, date, null, mysql-5.6

Using MySQL 5.6 I am trying to select the total `inspections` for each `month` in the past 12 months with an output of 0 if there are none. I appear to be missing something here as the output is all `NULL`. The `date_inspected` field is just a regular SQL `date`

From what I understood, the structure should be `[conditional statement, output variable, default value]` but even the 0 gets ignored in favor of NULL. I am trying to understand what I am doing wrong here.

Table:

```
Column          Type        Null    
id              int(11)     No           
inspector_id    int(11)     Yes          
company_id      int(11)     Yes      
date_inspected  date        No           
start_time      datetime    No           
end_time        datetime    No
```

Query:

```
SELECT
  SUM(IF(MONTH = 'Jan', total, 0)) AS 'Januari',
  SUM(IF(MONTH = 'Feb', total, 0)) AS 'Februari',
  SUM(IF(MONTH = 'Mar', total, 0)) AS 'Maart',
  SUM(IF(MONTH = 'Apr', total, 0)) AS 'April',
  SUM(IF(MONTH = 'May', total, 0)) AS 'Mei',
  SUM(IF(MONTH = 'Jun', total, 0)) AS 'Juni',
  SUM(IF(MONTH = 'Jul', total, 0)) AS 'Juli',
  SUM(IF(MONTH = 'Aug', total, 0)) AS 'Augustus',
  SUM(IF(MONTH = 'Sep', total, 0)) AS 'September',
  SUM(IF(MONTH = 'Oct', total, 0)) AS 'Oktober',
  SUM(IF(MONTH = 'Nov', total, 0)) AS 'November',
  SUM(IF(MONTH = 'Dec', total, 0)) AS 'December',
  SUM(total) AS all_months
  FROM (
        SELECT MONTH(date_inspected) AS MONTH, COUNT(*) AS total
        FROM inspection
        WHERE date_inspected BETWEEN NOW() AND Date_add(NOW(), interval - 12 month)
        GROUP BY MONTH
  ) AS SubTable
```

Output

```
{ ["Januari"]=> NULL 
["Februari"]=> NULL 
["Maart"]=> NULL 
["April"]=> NULL 
["Mei"]=> NULL 
["Juni"]=> NULL 
["Juli"]=> NULL 
["Augustus"]=> NULL 
["September"]=> NULL 
["Oktober"]=> NULL 
["November"]=> NULL 
["December"]=> NULL 
["all_months"]=> NULL }
```

*Update:*

SOLUTION by [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff)

```
SELECT
     SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date_inspected) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Januari',
     SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date_inspected) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Februari',
     SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date_inspected) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Maart',
     SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date_inspected) = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'April',
     SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date_inspected) = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Mei',
     SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date_inspected) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Juni',
     SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date_inspected) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Juli',
     SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date_inspected) = 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Augustus',
     SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date_inspected) = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'September',
     SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date_inspected) = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Oktober',
     SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date_inspected) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'November',
     SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date_inspected) = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'December'
FROM inspection
WHERE date_inspected BETWEEN Date_add(NOW(), interval - 12 month) AND  NOW()
```

As I understand it, we've given the `SUM()` a conditional CASE statement that if the current record's `date_inspected`'s MONTH is equal to the MySQL constant for that value, return true and add it to the total, else do nothing.

[More on MySQL CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html)

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Juergen is correct on one problem in your query.  Another is that `MONTH()` returns a number, not a string.

And, you can further simplify the query.  A subquery is not needed:

```
    SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date_inspected) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS 'Januari',
           SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date_inspected) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS 'Februari',
           . . .
    FROM inspection
    WHERE date_inspected BETWEEN Date_add(NOW(), interval - 12 month) AND NOW();
```

Comment: This worked though I had the remove the GROUP BY because it put every SUM result in its own row with all other values set to 0. I'm updating the question with the solution below it, you're a lifesaver.

Answer (score 3):

`between` must use the smaller value first and not the other way around. Change

```
BETWEEN NOW() AND Date_add(NOW(), interval - 12 month)
```

to

```
BETWEEN  Date_add(NOW(), interval - 12 month) and NOW()
```

And `month()` returns a number of the month and not the name.

Comment: It returns `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1111 Invalid use of group function` now though as far as I can tell the `GROUP BY` function should be able to use `MONTH(column_name)` as an argument. Strange